# How is this "ampersand operator" pointing the array index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm following a web performance course where the following piece of code is shared:

```
// Interesting operator

const objects = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 4 }];
let iterations = 10;
while (iterations--) {
  let sum = 0;
  const obj = objects[iterations & 3];
  console.log(obj.a);
}
```

I've never seen anything like `objects[iterations & 3]` before. The loop will iterate through the array but it never goes out of bounds. I searched through MDN and other websites for more information but I couldn't find this operator.

Any pointers? Thanks!

Here is the example in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-snowflake-gcmml?fontsize=14

Comment: `&` is bitwise AND. Was the code-writer *trying* to confuse readers of his code? Better to use `% 4`, it's a lot more intuitive.

Comment: Regarding MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND